# Getting error in command prompt while running the node server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-modules

I'm trying to run node app `server.js` with the imported code from GitHub but getting below error in the console. Not sure why I'm getting this error.

> Error :util.js:959 Object.setPrototypeOf(ctor.prototype, superCtor.prototype);

```
TypeError: Object.setPrototypeOf called on null or undefined
    at Function.setPrototypeOf (native)
    at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:959:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (businessvalidationexception.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at loader (/home/vagrant/Desktop/..../node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:126:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/vagrant/Desktop/..../node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
```

Comment: What is the app you're trying to run? Can you add a link to the git repo?

Comment: Capitalized title